# laravel 5 OOP structure/architecture advice

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5

I have a general question about how to implement the best practice of model structure for an application I'm building in Laravel 5.

So, at the moment I have things set up like this:

'**user**' model and table: id, email, password, admin level - this is really just the info for authenticating login.

'**user-details**' model and table: id, userID (foreign key for user table id field), name, address etc - all the other details

'**lesson-type**' model and table: id, teacherID (foreign key for user-details table id field), lesson-label etc - info about different types of lessons

At the moment I have a Teacher Controller in which I'm passing through to the view:
 - The info from the **User** table
 - The info from the **User-details** table
 - A list of different lesson types for the teacher from the **Lesson-type table**

But I kind of feel that all this should be tied together with one separate **Teacher model** which would extend the **User-details** model (and probably which in turn should extend the **User** model), but wouldn't have it's own table associated with it, but all the info pertaining to either updates for the User-details or the Lesson-types table would be stored in those relevant tables. Would this be correct?

(I should also say that users may alternatively be parents rather than teachers, and so would I would have a separate **Parents** model for all the properties and so on associated with parents)

I would then pass only the Teacher model object into the view and thus gain access to all the teacher info such as personal details and array of lesson types.

As I'm typing, this is sounding more and more to me like the right way to go, but it would be great to get some advice.

1 - technical implementation: I guess in the Teacher model, I'd populate all the relevant teacher into class variables (Name, array of lessons etc) in the constructor?

2 - am I over complicating this structure by having both Users AND Users details tables?

3 - Does what I'm proposing make the most structural sense in Laravel?

4 - just another thought I've just had, should the teacherID in the lesson-type table actually refer to the User table rather than the User-detail table... so user-detail and lesson-type would both be direct children of the user table??

**Very** much obliged for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't extend models like that unless there is a clear inheritance. From a logical standpoint, it just doesn't make any sense since you'll have to overwrite most of what is on the `User` model anyway. And what you don't overwrite will be incorrectly mapped to the database because they are 2 completely different tables. What you actually want to do is utilize Eloquent relationships.

For clarity, I am assuming this basic structure:

```
users - id
teachers - id, user_id
user_details - id, user_id
lesson_types - id, teacher_id
```

Those should be 4 completely different models all interconnected using the `Model::belongsTo()` method. So the `Teacher` model would be

```
class Teacher extends Model {
    public $table = 'teachers';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

When you query for a teacher, you can do `Teacher::with('user')->get()`. That will return all records from the teachers table and on each instance of the `Teacher` model, you'll be able to call `$teacher->user` and get the `User` instance associated with that teacher. That is a full model, not just extra data, so you have access to everything on the `User` Model, which is generally the main reason for extending

For your list of questions:

1. I may be misunderstanding you, but this isn't how an ORM works. I'd suggest going back and reading through the Eloquent docs (if you're running 5.0, I suggest reading 5.1's docs since they are much, much better)
2. It will depend on who you ask, but I tend to think so. If the data is clearly related and there is no reason for it to be shared across record types (for example, I generally have an `addresses` table that all records reference instead of having 5 address fields repeated on multiple tables), I believe it should all be on one table. It just makes it more difficult to manage later on if you have it in separate tables.

   There will be those who disagree and think that smaller scopes for each table are better and it will likely allow for quicker queries on extremely large datasets, but I don't think it's worth the extra trouble in the end
3. No, as I have explained above
4. The `teacher_id` column should reference the `teachers` table, assuming that lessons belong to teachers and cannot belong to just any user in the system. Using the ORM, you'll be able to do `$lesson->teacher->user->userDetails` to get that data

I really think you need to go back and read through the Eloquent docs. Your understanding of how Eloquent works and how it is meant to be used seems very basic and you are missing much of the finer details.

- [Basics](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)
- [Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)
- [Laracasts - Laravel Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) - You would benefit from watching Lesses 7-9, 11, 14, and 21

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, much appreciated.

I didn't do a perfect job of explaining myself, but you have confirmed what I was suspecting, that these models should be extended from the User/User Detail table (and the properties retrieved through the teacher model as a full object - just wasn't sure of the syntax to do this, thx 4 that!).

I have since merged the user and userdetails tables.

What you said about not overwriting the data in the parent models makes total sense....

Comment: ...If I can just clarify a little further though, there is no teacher table, as all the teacher info is contained in the user tables. so I have...
users - id | lesson_types - id, user_id (labeled as teacher_id)

just watched the relationship video and it makes more sense now... so with my current setup I'd call $user->lessonTypes. But this seems wrong calling it from User as users can be both parents AND teachers....

Comment: ... Should I set up a teacher table with: id(teacher id), user_id? the lesson table would then relate to this teachers model instead of the user table, so I would have $teacher->lessonTypes?

 Many thanks for your recommended reading too, it's pretty obvious that I'm just diving in at the deep end and learning 'on the job'! That's my job for the day though, to have a further read through these things :) Thanks once again for your help, and any further clarity you can boot my way!!